# How to use a button.click event to return to a tabitem

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB2010 and I want to be able to create a button.click event that will return the user to an open tabitem.  All my research is yielding information on how to create a closeable tab item, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Request the kind assistance of this community.  Hopefully, as I learn I can contribute.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the TabControl's [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) to the TabItem you wish to activate.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.  How do I do what you've suggested?  Do I assign a name to the tabitem and then use a code like TabControl.tabname.show()?

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: You can set a name on the tab item, like "theTabItem", and then use `tabControl.SelectedItem = theTabItem`

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  This didn't work, as there isn't a TabControl.SelectedItem.  What I see via intellisense is TabControl.SelectedItemProperty - this isn't the same thing is it?

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: I included the link to the SelectedItem property... What "TabControl" class are you using?  Is it a 3rd party control?

Comment: I'm using the class created by VB when I added the TabControl to the WPF Application.  Yeah, thanks for the link but I got the same thing - can't find selecteditem (even when I use the full name SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.PRIMITIVES) all I see is SelectedItemProperty.

Comment: Your suggestion finally worked.  It took me some tweaking around.  I realized that I had to assign a name to both the tabcontrol and its tabitems.  Thanks.